# Discover IMAP settings

Tags: php, email, imap, discovery

I'm trying to find a library or class that can help me support a discover function which will need to return the "suggested" IMAP settings in PHP.

```
host (str)
port (int)
ssl (boolean)
username (str) *optional
```

The user should be able to input their e-mail address and the script should return a suggestion of their current IMAP settings.

Comment: Are you wanting to have PHP determine the current settings for an email client?

Comment: Its fairly easy to write that yourself. nslookup the mx record for the domain specified to the right of the @ symbol that'll then give you the host name it points to ie: mail.domain.com or imap.domain.com do a quick socket connect (telnet style) to standard imap port 43? check see if its open if it is then you've got your hostname and port sorted if not then check for SSL port to be open if neither are open then imap isn't available.  easy as that and thats exactly how every device on the market does it iphone/android/bb etc

Comment: @Dave I think he's asking whether there's a library available to do that for him (which is a valid question, since you shouldn't reinvent the wheel ;-) )

Comment: @RobinKanters that's correct. I've been trying to even search library in another language than PHP (which I could convert to PHP eventually). Thought somebody probably would have had this before.

Comment: We should probably write this code and throw it in a git repo.. :P

Comment: @RobinKanters be my guest ;)

Comment: I suspect the reason nobody has ever done it is because its like 10 lines of code at most

Comment: @Dave if you think you could do it in a few lines maybe you can push me in the right direction with an example? Would be awesome!

Comment: Start here https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1312/How+do+I+check+to+see+if+POP3%7B47%7DIMAP+are+running%2C+and+how+do+I+fix+any+problems%3F#all/-test-imap-- commands for doing manual check with telnet implement that into your php you can work out how to explode an email address to get domain yourself check common domains for starters mail. pop3. imap. smtp.  Finally check here http://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mailnews/base/prefs/content/accountcreation/guessConfig.js see how thunderbird does it

Answer (score 0):

See [RFC 6186](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6186).

It's badly supported, though. Most people use the algorithm from the Thunderbird source code. But 6186 is the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently had a similar task of detecting mail server settings by email in PHP and wrote a small package for this purpose: https://packagist.org/packages/punarinta/email-auth

Here's the algorithm in brief:

- locate IMAP host

  - try imap.mail.domain
  - read MX record of email's domain
  - try mx-record.domain
  - try imap.mx-record.domain
  - get IP of mx-record.domain, lookup reversely by IP, try imap.reversed.domain
- locate IMAP port

  - for every possible host (see above) check various IMAP ports (993, 143)

Comment: Link-only answers are generally [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/204922) on Stack Overflow. In time it is possible for links to atrophy and become unavailable, meaning that your answer is useless to users in the future. It would be best if you could provide the general details of your answer in your actual post, citing your link as a reference.

Comment: OK, I'll try to do it. Thanks.

Comment: For smaller hosts, trying mail.domain is useful as well.

Comment: @Max, could you please give an example of such an email/domain? I'll check how that configuration looks like and will then enhance the algorithm.

Comment: Yeah, my self hosted one, but I'm not sharing my email address in public :)  I don't have examples of others off the top of my head, but mail.domain.com is not a rare name for the IMAP servers for hosted domains.

Comment: OK, thanks anyway! I'll add this kind of domains check as a fallback.